# Spring 5.3 and Hibernate 5.6 compatibility

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I would like to know if Spring 5.3 and Hibernate 5.6 are compatible. The only information I found is:

> Hibernate support has been upgraded to a Hibernate ORM 5.2+ baseline, with a focus on ORM 5.4.x. Please note that Hibernate Search needs to be upgraded to 5.11.6 for Spring Framework 5.3 JPA compatibility; see Hibernate JIRA.

From: [Upgrading to Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x)

Has anyone more information about if Spring 5.3 only compatible with Hibernate 5.4 or also with 5.6?

In the case of only Hibernate 5.4 compatible, is 5.4 EOL?